# Как программно открыть экран: "Разрешения приложений" для определенного приложения на Android?

Tags: java, android, permissions

Программный код для открытия экрана "Сведения о приложении" следующий:

```
private static final int REQUEST_STATE = 1;

. . .

public void openAppSettings() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_STATE);
}
```

Есть ли возможность непосредственно открыть экран "Разрешения приложений" для конкретного приложения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Согласно официальному видео (`Marshmallow permissions`) ([отметка 4:43](https://youtu.be/iZqDdvhTZj0?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc-YUddw59dYq61o3ynn3A4X&t=283)) вы должны сначала открыть страницу настроек приложения. Оттуда до редактирования разрешений один клик.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32983128/5330439)

Это связано с тем, что при диалоге с Пользователем уже выстроен порядок запроса Разрешений. Прямая ссылка нарушает этот порядок и злоупотребление ею может [надоедать](https://plus.google.com/+WolframRittmeyer/posts/HKxNFd5zHsh) Пользователю.

Comment: Жаль, что Гугель решает всё за нас((